# Passing chart type parameter to custom function as google chart function

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Currently i am creating chart using google chart. for this i have created one custom function called `myJchart` as below.

```
    function myJChart(ChartPackage,ChartType,ChartData,ChartTitel,ChartSubtitle,Chart3D,ChartHeight,ChartWidth,ChartDivID){

        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:[ChartPackage]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ChartData);
            var options = {
                title: ChartTitel,
                subtitle: ChartSubtitle,
                is3D: true,
                height: ChartHeight,
                width: ChartWidth               
                };


        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(ChartDivID));
            chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    }
```

And Calling function

```
myJChart('corechart','PieChart',<?php echo $jsonTable;?>,'test','test again',true,'600','800','chart_div');
```

this above function is working good.
now the problem is that when i pass the **`ChartType`** parameter to google  **`google.visualization.ChartType`**
i am getting below error message

**`Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.ChartType is not a function`**

i used **[ChartType]** but i got this error `Unexpected token [`
any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [ChartWrapper Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject) for this...

mainly because you only want to call `google.load` once.

ChartWrapper will dynamically load what it needs depending on the chart type.

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["controls"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(googleLoaded);

// test data
var rowData1 = [['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua  Guinea','Rwanda', 'Average'],
                ['2004/05', 165, 938, 522, 998, 450, 114.6],
                ['2005/06', 135, 1120, 599, 1268, 288, 382],
                ['2006/07', 157, 1167, 587, 807, 397, 623],
                ['2007/08', 139, 1110, 615, 968, 215, 409.4],
                ['2008/09', 136, 691, 629, 1026, 366, 569.6]];

function googleLoaded() {
    myJChart('corechart', 'BarChart', rowData1, 'test', 'test again', true, 600, 800, 'chart_div');
}

function myJChart(ChartPackage, ChartType, ChartData, ChartTitel, ChartSubtitle, Chart3D, ChartHeight, ChartWidth, ChartDivID){
    chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: ChartType,
        containerId: ChartDivID,
        dataTable: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(ChartData),
        options: {
            title: ChartTitel,
            subtitle: ChartSubtitle,
            is3D: Chart3D,
            height: ChartHeight,
            width: ChartWidth
        }
    });

    chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: perfect answer...ans thanx for the ChartWrapper

Comment: cheers! glad to help. check out [dashboards and controls](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)  and I'm working on something with the [ChartEditor](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_charteditor) to allow users to customize their own dashboard views...