# google pie chart error: Row given with size different than 0

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I am using google chars to draw pie and bar charts with data coming from a database. I am using PHP and JavaScript.

I have the following code:

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], callback: function(){
    // check what chart to draw (pie or bar chart)
    if(tipoghs[0] == 'PICH')
    {
        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Ventas');
        data.addColumn('number', titles[0]);

        for(var i = 0;i < size;i++)
        {
            data.addRows([[dfilas[i], parseFloat(dcolumnas[i])]]);
        }

        // Set chart options
        var options = 
        {
            'title' : 'Cantidad Total de Entradas',
            'width' : 400,
            'height': 300,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            chartArea: 
            {
                left: "3%",
                top: "10%",
                height: "100%",
                width: "70%"
            }
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('ficContainer'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    // check what chart to draw (pie or bar chart)
    else if(tipoghs[0] == 'COCH')
    {
        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Ventas');
        data.addColumn('number', titles[0]);

        for(var i = 0;i < size;i++)
        {
            data.addRows([[dfilas[i], parseFloat(dcolumnas[i])]]);
        }

        // Set chart options
        var options = 
        {
            title: titles[0],
            hAxis: 
            {
                viewWindow: 
                {
                    min: [7, 30],
                    max: [17, 30]
                }
            },
            vAxist: 
            {
                title: "Meses"
            }
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('ficContainer'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

I am doing an AJAX call to get the data from the server. One of the data points coming from the database is if I want to draw pie or bar chart (a condition you will find in the javascript code).

For some reason, when I open the website on IE 9 and I set the data point in the DB to be pie chart, it gives me the error: Row given with size different than 0.
Since it is a pie chart in the DB, it is passing through the IF condition. If I open in Google Chrome, it works (it doesn't give error message).

If I set the chart to be bar chart in the DB, it works in IE 9. When it is a bar chart, it goes through the ELSE in the javascript code below.

Does anyone know why when it passes through the IF (pie chart), it gives an error message in IE 9?

Comment: Probably not related, but I think you probably mean `vAxis` not `vAxist`.

Comment: Thanks but yeah, not related to the problem

Comment: would need to see the data to really help. if you want to create different charts dynamically, might I suggest using the [ChartWrapper Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject). This would eliminate the need for the `if` statement -- [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34633584/5090771)

Comment: I would look into your `data.addRows([[dfilas[i], parseFloat(dcolumnas[i])]]);` are you sure it shouldn't be `data.addRow` (without the s)? I mean you're only passing data for one row (I'm just assuming this, but it looks like that...).